# JQuery .live with a .change in the function inside an if stament

Tags: jquery

I'm starting over here...

I have this function...

```
 $('.Discount').live({
        focusout: function() { 

        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var CustDiscount = $('#CustDiscount:eq(0)').val();
        var DiscountIS = $('.DiscountIS:eq(0)', $tr).val();

        if  ((CustDiscount) > (DiscountIS)) {
                (Discount) = (CustDiscount);
        } else if 
            ((DiscountIS) > (CustDiscount)) {
                (Discount) = (DiscountIS);
        } else if
            ((DiscountIS) = (CustDiscount)) {
                (Discount) == (CustDiscount);
        }
            $('.Discount:eq(0)', $tr).val(Discount);
    } 
});
```

There is a `.live` function that will use the value of the Discount after that var is established. If the user tabs past the `.Discount` field the above function puts in the `(Discount)` based on the function. Now, what I would like to do is that if the user enters a different amount into the `.Discount` field it will use the entered amount and override the if statement. Right now it is defaulting to the `if statement`. What would be the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Tell us what you intend to do first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user inputs a value, it will be used. If the user leaves the field empty the if blocks will execute.  Is that what you want?

```
$('.Discount').change(function() {
    (Discount) = $(this).val();
    // If the field is cleared...
    if ((Discount) == '') {
        // ...calculate
        if ((CustDiscount) > (DiscountIS)) {
            (Discount) = (CustDiscount);
        } else if ((DiscountIS) > (CustDiscount)) {
            (Discount) = (DiscountIS);
        } else if ((DiscountIS) == (CustDiscount)) {
            (Discount) = (CustDiscount);
        }
        $(this).val(Discount);
    }
});
```

Note that `(Discount) = ('.Discount').val();` in your code probably should be `(Discount) = $('.Discount').val();`.

Edit for the comments:

```
// Function for calculating the discount
function calculateDiscount() {
    if ((CustDiscount) > (DiscountIS)) {
        return (CustDiscount);
    } else if ((DiscountIS) > (CustDiscount)) {
        return (DiscountIS);
    } else if ((DiscountIS) == (CustDiscount)) {
        return (CustDiscount);
    }
}

// Set the default value
$('.Discount').val(calculateDiscount());

$('.Discount').change(function() {
    // If the field is cleared...
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).val(calculateDiscount());
    }
});
```

Comment: No that's incorrect, look up the syntax for `jQuery.val()` Edit: disregard this comment now that this answer has been edited.

Comment: Yeah I know, I was referring to your answer having `.val() = (Discount)` before you fixed it. Edit: argg on the mobile site there's no comment delete button and now this comment refers to a deleted one..

Comment: Sorry about deleting the comment, didn't see your follow-up comment there. But I stand corrected. :)

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted. Lemme play around with it.

Comment: Question: Okay so I have the original if statement that I need to give me the Discount BEFORE the Discount would ever .change but as the if statement is now wrapped in a function it will not work right. Could I put the .change function inside the if statement at the end? So it would get called after the Discount was set, but only if it was changed buy the user?

Comment: @Monty, so you want to give it a default value? Did I understand correctly? Then just do `$('.Discount').val(VALUE_HERE);` before that `.change()` call.

Comment: The Default value would be the outcome of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try someting like:

```
$('.Discount').keyup(function() {
   //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to picture things as more event driven; some action takes place, then you respond to it.  Looking at your code, it looks like you are monitoring values, more than events.  It's a small, but important difference:

```
// selector = find the element you're interested in: $('.Discount')
// event = which action are you going to respond to: .change()
$('.Discount').change(function() {
   //your if block lives in here
});
```

You do not need to use `.live()` or `.on()` [for jQuery 1.7], unless your textboxes live in dynamically created rows.  If that is the case, you can do this

```
$('#tableName').on('change', '.Discount', function() {
   //your if block lives here
});
```

documentation: [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**Addition:**

For your `if`, statement, you may need to make use of the line below since `.change()` detects when the value changes, not when the value changes against the original value:

```
if ($(this).val() != this.defaultValue) {
}
```

Comment: Yes the rows are dynamic, this is just a small part of the form and it works off of a few different variables that's why the if statement. I'm using 1.6.2 so I'm using .live, also I want the function on the .Discount selector.